# Woocommerce product description image not showing

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

after i configure my woo-commerce website to PayPal payment service method my product description image hide for any unknow reason i am facing this error and cant resolve yet try some different thing but nothing works
Error

> Uncaught Error: Share '0' is not found

Site Url:
http://www.ribajackets.com/product/mens-gotham-jacket/

Comment: Issue is from Gillion theme

Comment: can you guide me to solve this

Comment: Check by switching theme and if the issue is gone, can confirm its the issue with theme. So only need to check in the theme

Answer (score 0):

Check the image path that you are providing to file.